# APNS Content Available Push not working in iOS 15

Tags: apple-push-notifications, payload, ios15, silent-notification, silentpush

APNS Content available push not received in iOS 15 device when app builds with Xcode 13.0,iOS 15 SDK.

Push payload data with content available:1 not working

```
{"aps":{"content-available":1},"update":"2|1"}
```

but normal notification message push working

```
{"aps":{"alert":"welcome"}}
```

is there any payload or configuration in the header field for the iOS 15 silent push message ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. According to [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app):

> The notification’s POST request should contain the apns-push-type header field with a value of background, and the apns-priority field with a value of 5. The APNs server requires the apns-push-type field when sending push notifications to Apple Watch, and recommends it for all platforms.

The header looks like this:

```
request_headers = {
    'apns-expiration': '0',
    'apns-priority': '5', # must be 5 for silent pushes, otherwise it will not be sent
    'apns-topic':'your_app_bundle_id',
    'authorization': 'bearer your_jwt_token'
    'apns-push-type': 'background' # this field is not required
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.